# My database SQL does not allow me to access a hint

Tags: python, database, user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter

It will not allow me to access my hints from my database, an error comes up.

Code:

```
def do_question(self):
    self.func1()
    #myGlobal + 1
    if myGlobal >5:
        import MathsvadersReal

    SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tblQuestion'
    cursor = Databaseconnector.SELECT(SQL)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    random_row = random.choice(rows)

    print random_row.QuestionID, random_row.Question, random_row.Hint, random_row.A1, random_row.A2, random_row.A3, random_row.A4, random_row.CorrectAnswer

    # create welcome label
    self.label1 = Tkinter.Label(self, bg ='yellow', text = (random_row.Question))
    self.label1.grid(row = 0, column = 6, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'E')

    self.label111 = Tkinter.Label(self, bg ='red', text = (random_row.QuestionID, "."))
    self.label111.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 4, sticky = 'W')
```

Hint Code:

```
def homepage_link(self):
    lbl = self.label111['text']
    SQL = 'SELECT Hint FROM tblQuestion WHERE QuestionID = ' + lbl  + ''
    print SQL
    cursor = Databaseconnector.SELECT(SQL)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    #row = rows
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Hint", (row.Hint))
```

ERROR:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'QuestionID = 9 .'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you retrieve from `self.label111['text']` is not a valid integer, you should remove the `"."` at the end of the text:

```
self.label111 = Tkinter.Label(self, bg ='red', text=random_row.QuestionID)
# ...
SQL = 'SELECT Hint FROM tblQuestion WHERE QuestionID = %s' % self.label111['text']
```

Comment: I changed that and got a new error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Hint'

Comment: Another error: TypeError: row indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @SmithJr Then it should be `rows[0][0]`. Please note that I'm not able to remember all the details of a Python module, so if you need further information I suggest you to ask a new question.